# How to ask every time for permission on activity start if the permission is not granted or denied previously

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location

I am working on an android app that needs user location, every time user logins into the app.

I have written code to get user location and works fine, but the problem is if the user denies permission twice it didn't ask again, here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String myLocation = "";
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (isGPSEnabled()) {
                    getCurrentLocation();
                } else {
                    turnOnGPS();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                getCurrentLocation();
            }
        }
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (isGPSEnabled()) {
                    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this)
                            .requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                                    super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                                    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this)
                                            .removeLocationUpdates(this);
                                    if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLocations().size() > 0) {
                                        int index = locationResult.getLocations().size() - 1;
                                        double latitude = locationResult.getLocations().get(index).getLatitude();
                                        double longitude = locationResult.getLocations().get(index).getLongitude();
                                        myLocation = "Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude;
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, Looper.getMainLooper());
                } else {
                    turnOnGPS();
                }
            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void turnOnGPS() {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getApplicationContext())
                .checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS is already tured on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            try {
                                ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, 2);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            //Device does not have location
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isGPSEnabled() {
        LocationManager locationManager = null;
        boolean isEnabled = false;
        if (locationManager == null) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
        isEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        return isEnabled;
    }
}
```

As, the user's location is mandatory for the working of app.  Now, I want the app to:

1- ask for permission on activity start, if the permission is not granted or denied previously.
2- if permission is granted then proceed further else close the activity.

So, how can I achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> but the problem is if the user denies permission twice it didn't ask
> again,

Yes, you cannot ask again once the user denies the permission with "Don't ask again" checked. This checkbox is normally checked by default on the second permission request. Beware that on api 11, there is no checkbox and the denial is automatic [auto-denial](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-denial) [auto-reset](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#auto-reset-permissions-unused-apps).

The way is that, you don't assume something about it, just put logic for handling it. If denied, you can only inform the user about the required permission. The official doc says: [ref](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#explain)

> If the ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() method returns
> PERMISSION_DENIED, call shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(). If
> this method returns true, show an educational UI to the user. In this
> UI, describe why the feature, which the user wants to enable, needs a
> particular permission.

[info](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-denial)

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the user has given permission or not using `checkSelfPermission` and if not then you ask for permission again else process with program flow.

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

         doStuff()

  } else {
    
         requestStoragePermission()
     }
```